# Silverlight XAML User Controls and Styles

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, styles

I have a few user controls inheriting from Button.  I have a handful of resources that I am switching between.

My problem is, the user defined control is not treated as a Button inside of the resource. I am having to change the TargetType to the name of my user control.

This is causing an issue since I have about 8 themes and a few user controls right now and probably a few more coming. So the changes I would have to make, if I needed to make 1 change to the buttons would be 8 themes X the number of user controls.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to keep from adding a style for each user control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to utilize the [BasedOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to come up with some cascading type styles, however if the controls are similiar I would look into trying to integrate the functionality into a single control with properties that would change the behavior/look instead of new controls for each ... of course that always depends on what you need.